# I need to calculate the area of each pizza slice from on how many slices there are and how to end the program when the number 0 by itself is entered

Tags: python

```
import math

# Constants for the minimum and maximum values
MINIMUM_PIZZA_DIAMETER = 8
MAXIMUM_PIZZA_DIAMETER = 24

# Constants for the number of slices in different sized pizzas
EXTRA_SMALL_PIZZA_SLICES = 6
SMALL_PIZZA_SLICES = 8
MEDIUM_PIZZA_SLICES = 10
LARGE_PIZZA_SLICES = 12
EXTRA_LARGE_PIZZA_SLICES = 16

# Constants for Diameter limits for each size of pizza
EXTRA_SMALL_DIAMETER_LIMIT = 12
SMALL_DIAMETER_LIMIT = 14
MEDIUM_DIAMETER_LIMIT = 16
LARGE_DIAMETER_LIMIT = 20
EXTRA_LARGE_DIAMETER_LIMIT = 24

# List for the Total amount of slices
TOTAL_SLICES = (6,8,10,12,16)

continue_input = True

is_valid = True
# Float variable for the number of slices in the user's pizza
user_diameter = 0.0
# Integer variable for the number of slices in the pizza
pizza_slices = 0
# Integer variable for the radius of a pizza
pizza_radius = 0
# Integer variable for the area of a pizza
pizza_area = 0
# Integer variable for the area of a pizza slice
pizza_slice_area = 0
# Integer variable for total possible number of slices
slices_possible = 0
# Integer for slices
slices = 0

while continue_input:
    is_valid = True
    while is_valid:
        try:
            user_diameter = float(input("Please enter the diameter of the pizza in inches or Enter 0 to end the program\t"))

            if MINIMUM_PIZZA_DIAMETER <= user_diameter <= MAXIMUM_PIZZA_DIAMETER:
                if user_diameter <= EXTRA_SMALL_DIAMETER_LIMIT:
                    pizza_slices = EXTRA_SMALL_PIZZA_SLICES
                    slices_possible = (6)
                    pizza_radius = user_diameter/2
                    pizza_area = (3.14*pizza_radius*pizza_radius)
                    pizza_slice_area = pizza_area/pizza_slices
                    pizza_slice_area = round(pizza_slice_area,2)
                    print(f"This Cuts {slices_possible} slices and gives an area of {pizza_slice_area} for each slice.")
                elif user_diameter <= SMALL_DIAMETER_LIMIT:
                    pizza_slices = SMALL_PIZZA_SLICES
                    slices_possible = (6,8)
                    pizza_radius = user_diameter/2
                    pizza_area = (3.14*pizza_radius*pizza_radius)
                    pizza_slice_area = pizza_area/pizza_slices
                    pizza_slice_area = round(pizza_slice_area,2)
                    print(f"This Cuts {slices_possible} slices and gives an area of {pizza_slice_area} for each slice.")
                elif user_diameter <= MEDIUM_DIAMETER_LIMIT:
                    pizza_slices = MEDIUM_PIZZA_SLICES
                    slices_possible = (6,8,10)
                    pizza_radius = user_diameter/2
                    pizza_area = (3.14*pizza_radius*pizza_radius)
                    pizza_slice_area = pizza_area/pizza_slices
                    pizza_slice_area = round(pizza_slice_area,2)
                    print(f"This Cuts {slices_possible} slices and gives an area of {pizza_slice_area} for each slice.")
                elif user_diameter <= LARGE_DIAMETER_LIMIT:
                    pizza_slices = LARGE_PIZZA_SLICES
                    slices_possible = (6,8,10,12)
                    pizza_radius = user_diameter/2
                    pizza_area = (3.14*pizza_radius*pizza_radius)
                    pizza_slice_area = pizza_area/pizza_slices
                    pizza_slice_area = round(pizza_slice_area,2)
                    print(f"This Cuts {slices_possible} slices and gives an area of {pizza_slice_area} for each slice.")
                else:
                    user_diameter <= EXTRA_LARGE_DIAMETER_LIMIT
                    pizza_slices = EXTRA_LARGE_PIZZA_SLICES
                    slices_possible = (6,8,10,12,16)
                    pizza_radius = user_diameter/2
                    pizza_area = (3.14*pizza_radius*pizza_radius)
                    pizza_slice_area = pizza_area/pizza_slices
                    pizza_slice_area = round(pizza_slice_area,2)
                    print(f"This Cuts {slices_possible} slices and gives an area of {pizza_slice_area} for each slice.")
                    
                continue_input = False
            else:
                print(f"You must enter a number between 8\" and 24\". You enter {user_diameter} ")
        except:
            print(f"You didn't enter a number ")
```

I am trying have this program tell me the area of each slice of pizza. The problem is that I need it to calculate the area of each slice of pizza from the possible amount slices and have it looping until I enter 0 by itself. For Extra Small its easy as it is only one number my problem is when there are multiple numbers. I don't know how to have it show the area of each slice there where 6,8,10,12,16 possible slices. I also don't know how to make the program end when I enter 0. I am new to coding so this is giving me a lot of trouble. I don't even know if I did the calculation correct.

I have tried what you see in the code above but what it should result in is this:

If I were to input 23.5" it should look like this.

```
Pizza Diameter: 23.5”
Cut in 6 slices results in an area of 72.29” per slice.
Cut in 8 slices results in an area of 54.22” per slice.
Cut in 10 slices results in an area of 43.37” per slice.
Cut in 12 slices results in an area of 36.14” per slice.
Cut in 16 slices results in an area of 27.11” per slice.
```

But what I get is this:

```
Cut in (6, 8, 10, 12, 16) slices results in an area of 27.09 for each slice.
```

I know I am missing something but my brain isn't working very well for this.

Comment: What's the purpose of `is_valid`? You never change it.

Comment: @Barmar I think that's my loop as I said I don't really have best knowledge of code but that makes my code loop as far as I know

Comment: Also, all the `user_diameter = 0.0` and such are totally useless, don't do that.

Comment: There's nothing that loops over all the values in `slices_possible`. You just print the whole tuple in the message.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille what should I do with it then?

Comment: Just remove these useless lines...

Comment: @Barmar what do I do then with `slices_possible` ?

Comment: You can initiate a loop: for i in slices_possible: and calculate the area for each value of i.

Comment: @Swifty how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for the `while is_valid:` loop.

And the loop for checking if the input is valid should just be around the `input()` call, not everything. You don't need the `continue_input` variable, just use `break` to end the loop.

To show all the different slice sizes, you need to loop over `slices_possible`.

Don't repeat all the calculations of the area of the pizza in each `if` block, since the formula is the same for all of them. Just set `slices_possible`, and move all the code that's the same to after that.

```
while True:
    try:
        user_diameter = float(input("Please enter the diameter of the pizza in inches or Enter 0 to end the program\t"))
        if MINIMUM_PIZZA_DIAMETER <= user_diameter <= MAXIMUM_PIZZA_DIAMETER:
            break
        print(f"You must enter a number between 8\" and 24\". You enter {user_diameter} ")
    except:
        print(f"You didn't enter a number ")

if user_diameter <= EXTRA_SMALL_DIAMETER_LIMIT:
    slices_possible = (6,)
elif user_diameter <= SMALL_DIAMETER_LIMIT:
    slices_possible = (6,8)
elif user_diameter <= MEDIUM_DIAMETER_LIMIT:
    slices_possible = (6,8,10)
elif user_diameter <= LARGE_DIAMETER_LIMIT:
    slices_possible = (6,8,10,12)
else:
    slices_possible = (6,8,10,12,16)

pizza_radius = user_diameter/2
pizza_area = (3.14*pizza_radius**2)
for pizza_slices in slices_possible:
    pizza_slice_area = pizza_area/pizza_slices
    print(f"This Cuts {slices_possible} slices and gives an area of {pizza_slice_area:.2f} for each slice.")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import math # pi

# Data: for each tuple: (name, pizza diameter, slices)
data = ( ("Extra small",12,6), ("Small", 14,8), ("Medium", 16,10), ("Large", 20,12), ("Extra large", 24, 16))

print( "     size   diam slices perSlice")
for name, diameter, slices in data:
  area = math.pi * (diameter / 2) **2
  print( "%-11s: %2d %4d %7.1f"% (name, diameter, slices, area/slices))
```

And result is:

```
     size   diam slices perSlice
Extra small: 12    6    18.8
Small      : 14    8    19.2
Medium     : 16   10    20.1
Large      : 20   12    26.2
Extra large: 24   16    28.3
```

You can easily add to the data set.